# Correlate messages in ELK by field

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, kibana, kibana-4, elastic-stack

Related to: [Combine logs and query in ELK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28429607/combine-logs-and-query-in-elk)

We are setting up ELK and would want to create a visualization in Kibana 4.
The issue here is that we want to relate between two different types of message.

To simplify:

- Message type 1 fields: message_type, common_id_number, byte_count,
  ...
- Message type 2 fields: message_type, common_id_number, hostname, ...

Both messages share the same index in elasticsearch.

[image]

As you can see we were trying to graph without taking that common_id_number into account, but it seems that we must use it. We don't know how yet, though.

Any help?

EDIT

These are the relevant field definitions in the ES template:

```
      "URIHost" : {
        "type" : "string",
        "norms" : {
          "enabled" : false
        },
        "fields" : {
          "raw" : {
            "type" : "string",
            "index" : "not_analyzed",
            "ignore_above" : 256
          }
        }
      },
      "Type" : {
        "type" : "string",
        "norms" : {
          "enabled" : false
        },
        "fields" : {
          "raw" : {
            "type" : "string",
            "index" : "not_analyzed",
            "ignore_above" : 256
          }
        }
      },
      "SessionID" : {
        "type" : "long"
      },
      "Bytes" : {
        "type" : "long"
      },
      "BytesReceived" : {
        "type" : "long"
      },
      "BytesSent" : {
        "type" : "long"
      },
```

This is a TRAFFIC type, edited document:

```
{
  "_index": "logstash-2015.11.05",
  "_type": "paloalto",
  "_id": "AVDZqdBjpQiRid-uxPjE",
  "_score": null,
  "_source": {
    "@version": "1",
    "@timestamp": "2015-11-05T21:59:55.543Z",
    "syslog_severity_code": 5,
    "syslog_facility_code": 1,
    "syslog_timestamp": "Nov  5 22:59:58",
    "Type": "TRAFFIC",
    "SessionID": 21713,
    "Bytes": 939,
    "BytesSent": 480,
    "BytesReceived": 459,
  },
  "fields": {
    "@timestamp": [
      1446760795543
    ]
  },
  "sort": [
    1446760795543
  ]
}
```

And this is a THREAT type document:

```
{
  "_index": "logstash-2015.11.05",
  "_type": "paloalto",
  "_id": "AVDZqVNIpQiRid-uxPjC",
  "_score": null,
  "_source": {
    "@version": "1",
    "@timestamp": "2015-11-05T21:59:23.440Z",
    "syslog_severity_code": 5,
    "syslog_facility_code": 1,
    "syslog_timestamp": "Nov  5 22:59:26",
    "Type": "THREAT",
    "SessionID": 21713,
    "URIHost": "whatever.nevermind.com",
    "URIPath": "/connectiontest.html"
  },
  "fields": {
    "@timestamp": [
      1446760763440
    ]
  },
  "sort": [
    1446760763440
  ]
}
```

This is the logstash "filter" configuration:

```
filter {
    if [type] == "paloalto" {
        syslog_pri {
            remove_field => [ "syslog_facility", "syslog_severity" ]
        }

        grok {
            match => {
                "message" => "%{SYSLOGTIMESTAMP:syslog_timestamp} %{HOSTNAME:hostname} %{INT},%{YEAR}/%{MONTHNUM}/%{MONTHDAY} %{TIME},%{INT},%{WORD:Type},%{GREEDYDATA:log}"
            }
            remove_field => [ "message" ]
        }

        if [Type] == "THREAT" {
            csv {
                source => "log"
                columns => [ "Threat_OR_ContentType", "ConfigVersion", "GenerateTime", "SourceAddress", "DestinationAddress", "NATSourceIP", "NATDestinationIP", "Rule", "SourceUser", "DestinationUser", "Application", "VirtualSystem", "SourceZone", "DestinationZone", "InboundInterface", "OutboundInterface", "LogAction", "TimeLogged", "SessionID", "RepeatCount", "SourcePort", "DestinationPort", "NATSourcePort", "NATDestinationPort", "Flags", "IPProtocol", "Action", "URL", "Threat_OR_ContentName", "reportid", "Category", "Severity", "Direction", "seqno", "actionflags", "SourceCountry", "DestinationCountry", "cpadding", "contenttype", "pcap_id", "filedigest", "cloud", "url_idx", "user_agent", "filetype", "xff", "referer", "sender", "subject", "recipient" ]
                remove_field => [ "log" ]
            }
            mutate {
                convert => {
                    "SessionID" => "integer"
                    "SourcePort" => "integer"
                    "DestinationPort" => "integer"
                    "NATSourcePort" => "integer"
                    "NATDestinationPort" => "integer"
                }
                remove_field => [ "ConfigVersion", "GenerateTime", "VirtualSystem", "InboundInterface", "OutboundInterface", "LogAction", "TimeLogged", "RepeatCount", "Flags", "Action", "reportid", "Severity", "seqno", "actionflags", "cpadding", "pcap_id", "filedigest", "recipient" ]
            }
            grok {
                match => {
                    "URL" => "%{URIHOST:URIHost}%{URIPATH:URIPath}(%{URIPARAM:URIParam})?"
                }
                remove_field => [ "URL" ]
            }
        }

        else if [Type] == "TRAFFIC" {
            csv {
                source => "log"
                columns => [ "Threat_OR_ContentType", "ConfigVersion", "GenerateTime", "SourceAddress", "DestinationAddress", "NATSourceIP", "NATDestinationIP", "Rule", "SourceUser", "DestinationUser", "Application", "VirtualSystem", "SourceZone", "DestinationZone", "InboundInterface", "OutboundInterface", "LogAction", "TimeLogged", "SessionID", "RepeatCount", "SourcePort", "DestinationPort", "NATSourcePort", "NATDestinationPort", "Flags", "IPProtocol", "Action", "Bytes", "BytesSent", "BytesReceived", "Packets", "StartTime", "ElapsedTimeInSecs", "Category", "Padding", "seqno", "actionflags", "SourceCountry", "DestinationCountry", "cpadding", "pkts_sent", "pkts_received", "session_end_reason" ]
                remove_field => [ "log" ]
            }
            mutate {
                convert => {
                    "SessionID" => "integer"
                    "SourcePort" => "integer"
                    "DestinationPort" => "integer"
                    "NATSourcePort" => "integer"
                    "NATDestinationPort" => "integer"
                    "Bytes" => "integer"
                    "BytesSent" => "integer"
                    "BytesReceived" => "integer"
                    "ElapsedTimeInSecs" => "integer"
                }
                remove_field => [ "ConfigVersion", "GenerateTime", "VirtualSystem", "InboundInterface", "OutboundInterface", "LogAction", "TimeLogged", "RepeatCount", "Flags", "Action", "Packets", "StartTime", "seqno", "actionflags", "cpadding", "pcap_id", "filedigest", "recipient" ]
            }
        }

        date {
            match => [ "syslog_timastamp", "MMM  d HH:mm:ss", "MMM dd HH:mm:ss" ]
            timezone => "CET"
            remove_field => [ "syslog_timestamp" ]
        }
    }
}
```

What we are trying to do is to visualize URIHost terms as X axis and Bytes, BytesSent and BytesReceived sums as Y axis.

Comment: What can be the values of the `message_type` field and do "type 1" messages always come before "type 2" ones?

Comment: Also can you share your existing Logstash configuration so people are not guessing on your setup?

Comment: "As you can see" means "please stare at my screen shot and try to reverse engineer what I meant to do".  Can you better describe the data that exists in elasticsearch (maybe a table with a real sample) and how you would like this data presented (show us how it should be combined, etc, just in a table), and then better describe your issues with visualizing it.

Comment: @Val: One or many "THREAT" type messages should come before a single "TRAFFIC" type message

Comment: Thanks, so to sum up, you have 1+ THREAT logs and 1 ending TRAFFIC log, all of which share the same `SessionID`? Is that correct? In case you have two or more THREAT logs, do you also want to aggregate them together?

Comment: @Val: Correct, one or several THREAT messages share the same SessionID with a single TRAFFIC end-session message. Can we display those ES aggregations (https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/aggregations.html) in Kibana? Could you answer with an example?

Comment: I'll come up with something, I just need to know what happens in the case there are several THREAT messages, will they contain different `URIHost` values or will it always be the same given the same `SessionID`?

Comment: SessionID refer to TCP sessions identifiers. If a TCP session to a host is reused for different HTTP requests then those THREAT messages related to each request will share the SessionID related to the underlying TCP connection.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you can use the [`aggregate` filter](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-filters-aggregate.html) to carry out your task. The `aggregate` filter provides support for aggregating several log lines into one single event based on a common field value. In your case, the common field we're going to use will be the `SessionID` field.

Then we need another field to detect the first event vs the second/last event that should be aggregated. In your case, this would be the `Type` field.

You need to change your current configuration like this:

```
filter {

    ... all other filters

    if [Type] == "THREAT" {
        ... all other filters

        aggregate {
            task_id => "%{SessionID}"
            code => "map['URIHost'] = event['URIHost']; map['URIPath'] = event['URIPath']"
        }
    }

    else if [Type] == "TRAFFIC" {
        ... all other filters

        aggregate {
            task_id => "%{SessionID}"
            code => "event['URIHost'] = map['URIHost']; event['URIPath'] = map['URIPath']"
            end_of_task => true
            timeout => 120
        }
    }
}
```

The general idea is that when Logstash encounters `THREAT` logs it will temporarily store the `URIHost` and `URIPath` in the in-memory event map, and then when a `TRAFFIC` log comes in, the `URIHost` and `URIPath` fields will be added to the event. You can copy other fields, too, if needed. You can also adapt the timeout (in seconds) depending on how long you expect a `TRAFFIC` event to come in after the last `THREAT` event.

In the end, you'll get documents with data merged from both `THREAT` and `TRAFFIC` log lines and you can easily create the visualization showing bytes count per `URIHost` as shown on your screenshot.

Comment: I left out the URIPath from the analysis to make URIHost stand out better. Thank you!